# Php !is_valid_type($image) is only working on one instance of an array

Tags: php, sql, image, image-uploading, validating

Hey guys what I'm trying to do is build an upload page for various games across different game consoles. I will admit I am new to php and I'm just trying to figure things out.I have ran into a strange problem via uploading images. I do not understand why this fails because one attribute in the array works perfectly fine. It uploads the results from the form with no problem. The other three attributes all fail. Using the exact same function and methods.

```
//// this the form block for uploading ////


<form action="process.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <!--xbox -->
                <div class="form">
                    <h3>Xbox 360</h3>

                    <!-- title of post/ game name -->
                    <p><label for="xboxtitle"> Title of Game </lable></p>
                    <input type="text" name="xboxtitle"  size=20 /><br />

                    <!-- image uploader -->
                    <p><label for="xbox-image">Game Image:</label><sup>*png, png, bmp, jpeg and jpg only!</sup></p>
                    <input type="file" name="xboximage" /><br />
                    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />

                    <!-- large text box -->
                    <p><label for="xboxtext">Displayed text:</label><sup> * limit of 250 characters allowed.</sup></p>
                    <textarea cols=40 rows=10 name="xboxtext"></textarea>

                    <!-- price box -->
                        <p><label for="xboxprice">Price of item</label></p>
                        <input type="text" name="xboxprice" size=8 /><br />

                </div>                  



<!-- p3 -->
                <div class="form">

                    <h3>Playstation 3</h3>

                    <!-- title of post/ game name -->
                    <p><label for="ps3title"> Title of Game </lable></p>
                    <input type="text" name="ps3title" size=20 /><br />

                    <!-- image uploader -->
                    <p><label for="ps3image">Game Image:</label><sup>*png, png, bmp, jpeg and jpg only!</sup></p>
                    <input type="file" name="ps3image" /><br />
                    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />

                    <!-- large text box -->
                    <p><label for="ps3text">Displayed text:</label><sup> * limit of 250 characters allowed.</sup></p>
                    <textarea cols=40 rows=10 name="ps3text"></textarea>

                    <!-- price box -->
                        <p><label for="ps3price">Price of item</label></p>
                        <input type="text" name="ps3price" size=8 /><br />


                </div>
<!-- wii -->
                <div class="form">
                    <h3>Wii</h3>

                    <!-- title of post/ game name -->
                    <p><label for="wiititle"> Title of Game </lable></p>
                    <input type="text" name="wiititle" size=20 /><br />

                    <!-- image uploader -->
                    <p><label for="wiiimage">Game Image:</label><sup>*png, png, bmp, jpeg and jpg only!</sup></p>
                    <input type="file" name="wiiimage" /><br />
                    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />

                    <!-- large text box -->
                    <p><label for="wiitext">Displayed text:</label><sup> * limit of 250 characters allowed.</sup></p>
                    <textarea cols=40 rows=10 name="wiitext"></textarea>

                    <!-- price box -->
                        <p><label for="wiiprice">Price of item</label></p>
                        <input type="text" name="wiiprice" size=8 /><br />

                    </div>



<!-- PC -->
                <div class="form">
                    <h3>PC</h3>

                    <!-- title of post/ game name -->
                    <p><label for="pctitle"> Title of Game </lable></p>
                    <input type="text" name="pctitle" size=20 /><br />

                    <!-- image uploader -->
                    <p><label for="pcimage">Game Image:</label><sup>*png, png, bmp, jpeg and jpg only!</sup></p>
                    <input type="file" name="pcimage" /><br />
                    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />

                    <!-- large text box -->
                    <p><label for="pctext">Displayed text:</label><sup> * limit of 250 characters allowed.</sup></p>
                    <textarea cols=40 rows=10 name="pctext"></textarea>

                    <!-- price box -->
                        <p><label for="pcprice">Price of item</label></p>
                        <input type="text" name="pcprice" size=8 /><br />

                </div>
        <p><input type="submit" id="submit" class="bigbutton" value="Upload" /></p>
</form>




///// this is the process.php page ///
<?php
include ("includes/logincheck.php");
?>

<?php

// Call our connection file
require("dbacess.php");


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // create validating image types function
function is_valid_type($file)
{
    // This is an array that holds all the valid image MIME types
    $valid_types = array("image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/bmp", "image/gif", "image/png");

    if (in_array($file['type'], $valid_types))
        return 1;
    return 0;
}


// declare possible forms in array.
$arr = array("xbox","ps3", "wii",  "pc");

// push the array through the following code
//while giving $value the proper form prefix
foreach ($arr as &$value) {

//$value Variables 
   $title = $_POST[$value . 'title'];
   $text = $_POST[$value . 'text'];
   $price = $_POST[$value . 'price'];
   $image = $_FILES[$value .'image'];

//validate info or redirect
if ($title && $text && $price && $image['name'] != "" ) 
    {

    // Sanitize our inputs
   $title = mysql_real_escape_string($title);
   $text = mysql_real_escape_string($text);
   $price = mysql_real_escape_string($price);
   $image['name'] = mysql_real_escape_string($image['name']);

    // Build our target path full string.  This is where the file will be moved to
   // Build Partial Target Path
    $TARGET_PATH = "../../images/newreleasesuploads/";
    $TARGET_PATH .= "$value/";

    //creates upload path
    $UPLOAD_PATH = $TARGET_PATH;
    $UPLOAD_PATH .= $image['name'];


    // Check to make sure that our file is actually an image
    // You check the file type instead of the extension because the extension can easily be faked
    if (!is_valid_type($image))
    {
        $_SESSION['error'] = "You must upload a jpeg, gif, png, or bmp in {$value} field. Please select a correct file type.";
        header("Location: welcome.php");
        exit;
    }

    // Here we check to see if a file with that name already exists
    // You could get past filename problems by appending a timestamp to the filename and then continuing
    if (file_exists($UPLOAD_PATH))
    {
        $_SESSION['error'] = "A file with that name already exists when trying to update $value page. Please rename file something different or remove the existing files";
        header("Location: welcome.php");
        exit;
    }

    //create current date variable
    $date = date("Y-m-d");
    $date .= date(" h:i:s");
    // count # of entries
    $entry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM new{$value}");
    $NUMBER_OF_ROWS = mysql_num_rows($entry);

    // Count # of entries delete if index is 10 or more.
    if($NUMBER_OF_ROWS >=10){

        // find oldest entry by date
            $sqldate ="SELECT * FROM new{$value}
            WHERE date = (SELECT MIN(date) FROM new{$value})";
            $oldestdate = mysql_query($sqldate) or die ("could not access DB to find oldest entry" . mysql_error());

            //grabs data from that row
            $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($oldestdate);

            //adds filename to delete path
            $DELETE =$TARGET_PATH;
            $DELETE .=$row['filename'];

            // parse row date to variable
            $deletedate = $row['id'];

            //terminates entry
            $deletedate = "DELETE FROM new{$value}
            WHERE id = $deletedate";
            $deleteoldest = mysql_query($deletedate) or die ("could not delete oldest date entry" . mysql_error());

            //terminates file
            unlink($DELETE);

            $_SESSION['message'] .= "The oldest entry was deleted to make room for the new upload.";


        }

    // attempt to move the file from its temporary directory to its new home
    if (move_uploaded_file($image['tmp_name'], $UPLOAD_PATH))
    {   

        // Placing a reference of the images location into the database, *not* putting the image into the database.
        $sql = "insert into new{$value} (date, title, description, price, filename) values ('$date', '$title', '$text', '$price',  '" . $image['name'] . "' )";
        $result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Could not insert data into DB: " . mysql_error());
        //message to let user know image was uploaded correctly
        $_SESSION['message'] .= "The {$value} entry was uploaded correctly";


    }

    else    {
        // A common cause of file moving failures is because of bad permissions on the directory attempting to be written to
        // Make sure you chmod the directory to be writable also make sure directory is not READ ONLY
        $_SESSION['error'] = "Could not upload file.  Check read/write permissions on the directory";
        header("Location: welcome.php");
        exit;

    }
}


// declare variable for error display
$i = 0;
// validate to make sure all are filled
if($title !=""){$i++;}
if($text !=""){$i++;}
if($price !=""){$i++;}
if($image['name'] !=""){$i++;}

elseif ($i!=0) {


    //validate that more then one but not all box
        $_SESSION['error'] = "Only $i of the fields for $value were filled. Please refill all fields or no fields for $value";
        header("Location: welcome.php");
        exit;

    }


}



// return to upload page
header("Location: welcome.php");
        exit;
?>
```

Whats happening is the xbox value in the array pushes through however ps3 wii and pc all send back the error "You must upload a jpeg, gif, png, or bmp in ps3 field. Please select a correct file type." which it should if the image is a wrong file type. However I can upload the same image simultaneously or singularly and  the xbox will pass every time while the others will fail. Could anyone tell me why this is? and possibly how to fix it?

Thanks for your time in advance

Comment: The *relevant* code shouldn't be too long for you to post here. Most problems only relate to no more than 20-30 lines. Please post the *relevant* code.

Comment: Copy, paste, select, Ctrl+K. Man, that was a pain. And yes, the code *is* too long.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed my own problem after doing some more research I had two options. The problem was that I was trying to upload multiple files without having the configuration on Apache. 
option 1) modify the form like so (this allows only one upload at a time)

```
                <div class="form">
                <form action="newreleasesprocess.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <h3>Playstation 3</h3>

                <!-- title of post/ game name -->
                <p><label for="ps3title"> Title of Game </lable></p>
                <input type="text" name="ps3title" size=20 /><br />

                <!-- image uploader -->
                <p><label for="ps3image">Game Image:</label><sup>*png, png, bmp, jpeg and jpg only!</sup></p>
                <input type="file" name="ps3image" /><br />
                <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />

                <!-- large text box -->
                <p><label for="ps3text">Displayed text:</label><sup> * limit of 250 characters allowed.</sup></p>
                <textarea cols=40 rows=10 name="ps3text"></textarea>

                <!-- price box -->
                    <p><label for="ps3price">Price of item</label></p>
                    <input type="text" name="ps3price" size=8 /><br />
                    <p><input type="submit" id="submit"  value="Upload" /></p>
    </form>


            </div>
```

However this gets rid of multiple uploads at once and for what I am using it for this is not fine.

option 2) reconfigure the max_file_uploads in the configuration .ini from 1 to 4( or what ever you want)

---

I went with option 2.

hope this solution helps anyone else who encounters the same issue
Thanks again to anyone that looked into my problem